# Batch file error - The system cannot find the file abc.csv

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This .bat file splits my csv large files.

Code works perfectly fine when i run on local.
My code when on local looks like this

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set target_folder=C:\Users\username\Desktop\splitted-files
if not exist %target_folder% mkdir %target_folder%
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "C:\Users\username\Desktop\split-large-csv-files\*.csv"') do (



    REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
    SET filename=%%a
    REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
    SET LPF=3000
    REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
    SET SFN=splitfile
    REM Do not change beyond this line.

    SET SFX=!filename!
    SET /A LineNum=0
    SET /A FileNum=1

    For /F "delims==" %%l in (!filename!) Do (
        SET /A LineNum+=1

        echo %%l >>%target_folder%\SFN!!FileNum!.!SFX!

        if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
        SET /A LineNum=0
        SET /A FileNum+=1
        )

    )
)
endlocal
Pause
```

Now keeping the file at C-drive & change my target folder and source folder to W-Drive (a network drive that is already mapped to a drive letter) my code looks like this, I have just changed the path for target folder and source in for loop.
It starts giving me an error saying `The system cannot find the file abc.csv`

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set target_folder=W:\Automation\Task\all-file-split
if not exist %target_folder% mkdir %target_folder%
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "W:\Automation\Task\check-file-split-here\*.csv"') do (



    REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
    SET filename=%%a
    REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
    SET LPF=3000
    REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
    SET SFN=splitfile
    REM Do not change beyond this line.

    SET SFX=!filename!
    SET /A LineNum=0
    SET /A FileNum=1

    For /F "delims==" %%l in (!filename!) Do (
        SET /A LineNum+=1

        echo %%l >>%target_folder%\SFN!!FileNum!.!SFX!

        if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
        SET /A LineNum=0
        SET /A FileNum+=1
        )

    )
)
pause
```

I am not getting where am I going wrong
Thanks

**Edit**
So after all the changes my code looks like this

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set target_folder=W:\Automation\Task\all-splitted-files
if not exist %target_folder% mkdir %target_folder%
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "Automation\Task\csv-file\*.csv"') do (

    REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
    SET "filename=%%~nxa"
    REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
    SET LPF=800
    REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
    SET SFN=splitfile
    REM Do not change beyond this line.

    SET SFX=!filename!
    SET /A LineNum=0
    SET /A FileNum=1

    For /F "usebackq delims==" %%l in ("%%~fa") Do (
        SET /A LineNum+=1

        echo %%l >>%target_folder%\!SFN!!FileNum!.!SFX!

        if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
        SET /A LineNum=0
        SET /A FileNum+=1
        )

    )
)
```

Comment: Is W: drive a network drive that you have mapped already? If so that would be your issue.

Comment: Yes its a network drive which is already mapped.
I am working on windows machine.

Comment: I am so sorry. I have made few changes in my question. 
Yes file works fine when it is on W Drive but does not when it is on C drive i.e. on desktop.

Comment: Nope here it is just taking the filename in a variable `filename` which will be used to name the file after splitting

Comment: But this is working great when target and source folder are on desktop too!

Comment: My .bat file is on desktop. All the csv files are on W-drive `W:\Automation\Task\check-file-split-here\*.csv` and after splitting it has to store also on W-Drive i.e. `target_folder=W:\Automation\Task\all-file-split`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, Just maybe, you have **your csv file open** , which will generate the error

***"Batch file error - The system cannot find the file abc.csv"***

Try closing the opened CSV file and run you batch file.

I had wasted an Hour because of this.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a network drive that is already mapped in Windows from a batch file, the permissions of the network drive access will most likely not match the permissions of the security context which the batch file is running under.

You are better off mapping the network drive within the batch script.

```
net use R: \\servername\folder [password] /USER:domain\username
```

And then remove it at the end of the script.

```
net use R: /delete
```

Comment: What would be the password of a folder? I don't have any!!

Comment: Password is optional and would be the password of the user specified /USER:domain\username. Both user and password is only required if the account running the batch script does not have access to the network path.

Comment: I have chain of bat files getting executed. In one of the bat file I was successful in accessing W- Drive.
So I don't think security can be an issue

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET "target_folder=W:\Automation\Task\all-file-split"
    if not exist "%target_folder%" mkdir "%target_folder%"

    SET "source_folder=W:\Automation\Task\check-file-split-here"

    for %%a IN ("%source_folder%\*.csv") do (

        REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
        SET "filename=%%~nxa"

        REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
        SET "LPF=3000"

        REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
        SET "SFN=splitfile"

        REM Do not change beyond this line.
        SET "SFX=!filename!"
        SET /A "LineNum=0"
        SET /A "FileNum=1"

        For /F "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%%~fa") Do (
            SET /A "LineNum+=1"

            echo(%%l >>"%target_folder%\!SFN!!FileNum!.!SFX!"

            if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
                SET /A "LineNum=0"
                SET /A "FileNum+=1"
            )

        )
    )
pause
```

Changes from your code:

```
SET "filename=%%~nxa"
```

Uses only file name and extension

```
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%%~fa") Do (
```

Changed to use the full file path to the file being processed. Included `usebackq` to quote the full path to the file.

```
echo(%%l >>"%target_folder%\!SFN!!FileNum!.!SFX!"
```

Added a missing exclamation point

All paths quoted

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I did as you asked. It is creating file with proper filename but content is incorrect it is adding path` C:\Users\username\Desktop\adword-google bat files\abc.com.au.csv` as content

Comment: @Peeny, did you include the `usebackq`? Without it the quoted file name is taken as a string, not a file reference

Comment: Ah! I had forgotten...I added!...tested!... It gives me an error saying `The system cannot find the C:\Users\username\Desktop\bat-files\filename.csv` and
`C:\Users\username\Desktop\bat-files\` This path is where my bat file is situated

Comment: @Penny, can you update the question with the code you are trying? There is something missing in it to get that file reference.

Comment: @Penny, the problem was in the enumeration of the source files. I've updated the code in my answer. Changed `for /f` structure into a simple `for` that will iterate over the files and that will hold the correct reference to the folder containing the source file.

Comment: @Penny, in your code, the line will look as `for %%a IN ("Automation\Task\csv-file\*.csv") do (`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you change `::SET filename...` to `rem SET filename...`.

The `::-comment` is actually a broken label and labels tend to terminate blocks, hence your `for...%%a` loop terminates at the "label"